# Is there a function that computes the probability of a sequence T of observations given a hidden Markov model on hmmlearn?

Tags: python-3.x, hmmlearn

I have a GaussianHMM that I have fitted using hmmlearn.fit function. I also have a bunch of sequences of observations and I want to compute the probability of each sequence happening given my fitted model. I looked into hmmlearn's documentation and I couldn't quite find a method that does what I want. In this case, do I just have to code the forward-backward algorithm? In case I code the forward-backward, I would also need the emission matrix, which is not given by hmmlearn.

Anyone has an advice regarding this? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also have a bunch of sequences of observations and I want to compute the probability of each sequence happening given my fitted model

1. What you might be looking for is the `score` function, to evaluate the probability of sequence (ie. `model.score(X)`). Note that this is the log probability, as `hmmlearn` adjusts for underflow error.

> In case I code the forward-backward, I would also need the emission matrix, which is not given by hmmlearn.

2. While the `GaussianHMM` does not have an emission matrix, you can choose to discretize your emissions and utilize `MultinomialHMM`, which allows you to specify and also later extract the emission matrix `model.emissionprob_`.